# Scheduled task does not run in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I have the need to create scheduled task programmatically so @scheduled won't work

So far I have

```
@Component
public class ScheduleBean {

    @Bean
    public ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar() {
        ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar = new ScheduledTaskRegistrar();
        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler());
        return scheduledTaskRegistrar;
    }

    public TaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setPoolSize(20);
        return scheduler;
    }
}
```

and

```
private void createJob() {
        ZonedDateTime zoned = LocalDate.now().atTime(11, 0);         

        scheduledTaskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        sendUpdates();
                    }
                },
                new Trigger() {
                    @Override
                    public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
                        return Date.from(zoned.toInstant());
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

and

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I expect the task to run at 11am but it doesn't

Comment: Why will the `createJob()` method ever run?  I don't see it referenced anywhere, nor is it adorned with any annotations that would cause Spring to see it.  There must be more code than this...at least the code around `createJob()` that defines the class it's in.

Answer (score 0):

It's because when `addTriggerTask` method is called, all configured tasks are already scheduled to be executed. No other tasks will be getting accepted. Ideally in this case, it should throw an exception, but it doesn't. So one simple / naive solution is to call `afterPropertiesSet()` method after adding trigger task, which internally calls `scheduleTasks()`.  `scheduleTasks()` is protected method so not directly accessible.

```
scheduledTaskRegistrar.afterPropertiesSet();
```

Recommended way is to let your configuration class implement `SchedulingConfigurer` and implements its `configureTasks` method.

```
@Configuration
public class ScheduleBeanConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {


    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar) {
        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler());
        scheduledTaskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(runnableTask(), trigger());
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setPoolSize(20);
        return scheduler;
    }

    public Runnable runnableTask() {
        return () -> {
             // you can autowire your update sender class and call sendUpdates() here
            sendUpdates();
        };
    }

    public Trigger trigger() {
        return (triggerContext) -> {
            // modify your trigger as per ur requirement
            return Date.from(Instant.now());
        };
    }
}
```